# Loading JPEG file from resources in MFC C++ application

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, jpeg, embedded-resource

The following code works correctly under Windows XP:

```
CImage image;

RECT destRect;

int nResource = 10;

CResourceStream stream(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nResource), _T("JPEG")); 

HRESULT hr = image.Load(&stream);

image.Draw(hDC, destRect);
```

But on Windows 7 `image.Load` returns `E_FAIL` though creating `CResourceStream` reads JPEG file from resources correctly.

Debugging gives the following result:

`GdipCreateBitmapFromStream` returns `InvalidParameter`.

What the problem can be?

JPEG is a custom category in resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I used this solution from codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/cgdiplusbitmap.aspx

It is a thin wrapper for GDI+ which is able to load JPEG files (and others) under Windows 7 perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. His article could be slightly simpler by letting CreateStreamOnHGlobal handle the memory and using CImage::Load (since LoadFromResource will not load jpg's).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use "JPG" not "JPEG".

Comment: JPEG is the name of custom category in resources, it can't influence creating of bitmap from stream. But anyway I tried your suggestion - it didn't help.