# Trying to display a CImage on a CDialog in OnPaint handler

Tags: mfc, cimage

I have a JPG resource in my MFC application. I try to load it like this in `OnInitDialog`:

```
m_imgSplash.LoadFromResource(AfxGetResourceHandle(), IDR_SPLASHSCREEN);
```

Then, in the `OnPaint` handler I do the following:

```
void CSplashDlg::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    m_imgSplash.Draw(dc.GetSafeHdc(), m_rctSplash);
}
```

But I am not seeing my image ...

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829107/loading-jpeg-file-from-resources-in-mfc-c-application/3841693) but `CResourceStream` is unknown.

Comment: What is your definition of `m_imgSplash`?

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica `CImage`

Comment: OK, and how is your `IDR_SPLASHSCREEN` defined (in the .rc script)?

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica  I am just trying this a moment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719437/2287576

Comment: `CImage::LoadFromResource` works for bitmap only. You can use `CPngImage` to load jpeg from resource. Your Jpeg resource has to be labeled as `PNG` type, like so: `IDI_JPEG1 PNG "file.jpg"`. Then attach the handle to `CImage` object, `m_image.Attach((HBITMAP)pngImage.Detach())`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Does the `CPngImage` object have to exist for as long at the `CImage`? I can always convert my JPG to a PNG anyway and add it again as a new resource.

Comment: `pngImage` is temporary. Basically `m_image.Attach((HBITMAP)pngImage.Detach())` will transfer the image to `m_image`, and you no longer need `CPngImage`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It works. Much simpler code! Thanks. Question: what type of exception does the `Attach` throw since it is not documented.

Comment: I don't know. Just make sure `pngImage.Load(...)` was successful, before calling `image.Attach((HBITMAP)png.Detach())`. You can also use `m_image.IsNull()` to make sure `m_image` is valid.